# Group by multiple columns in elastic search with specific result set

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to ES and i have some specific requirement, my document look like this

```
{
    "_index" : "bidder_server_stats",
    "_type" : "doc",
    "_id" : "_NTrHGQBv0YTjfMi0Ord",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "avg_price" : 5.8,
      "bc" : "2513",
      "log_dt_st" : "2018-06-08T06:36:16.073Z",
      "nid" : "1",
      "cc" : "880",
      "host" : "ip-172-31-18-62.ec2.internal",
      "country" : "us"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "bidder_server_stats",
    "_type" : "doc",
    "_id" : "_NTrHGQBv0YTjfMi0Ord",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "avg_price" : 10,
      "bc" : "2514",
      "log_dt_st" : "2018-06-08T06:36:16.073Z",
      "nid" : "1",
      "cc" : "880",
      "host" : "ip-172-31-18-62.ec2.internal",
      "country" : "us"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "bidder_server_stats",
    "_type" : "doc",
    "_id" : "_NTrHGQBv0YTjfMi0Ord",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "avg_price" : 11,
      "bc" : "2513",
      "log_dt_st" : "2018-06-08T06:36:16.073Z",
      "nid" : "1",
      "cc" : "880",
      "host" : "ip-172-31-18-62.ec2.internal",
      "country" : "us"
    }
  }
```

Now i need the result as i get using below query

```
select bc,log_dt_st,sum(avg_price) from table group by bc,log_dt_st.
```

How can we do this in elasticsearch. And i want only these three columns in result set (i.e. _source).

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with [sub-aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/search-aggregations.html#_structuring_aggregations). Starting from ES 6.1, [`composite`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.1/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html) aggregation could also come handy (although it is still experimental).

The query might look like this:

```
POST bidder_server_stats/doc/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by bc": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "bc"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "by log_dt_st": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "log_dt_st"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "sum(avg_price)": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "avg_price"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the response would look like this:

```
{
  ...
  "aggregations": {
    "by bc": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "2513",
          "doc_count": 2,
          "by log_dt_st": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": 1528439776073,
                "key_as_string": "2018-06-08T06:36:16.073Z",
                "doc_count": 2,
                "sum(avg_price)": {
                  "value": 16.800000190734863
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "2514",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "by log_dt_st": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": 1528439776073,
                "key_as_string": "2018-06-08T06:36:16.073Z",
                "doc_count": 1,
                "sum(avg_price)": {
                  "value": 10
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Few moments to consider:

- `bc` should have `keyword` type (to be able to do [`terms`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) aggregation on it)
- `terms` aggregation only returns top-10 buckets by default; you may be interested in `size` and `sort` options of this aggregation

**Update**: Responding to the questions from the comments since it will improve the answer.

#### Can we have some more fields in result set without adding them into aggregations?

No, not directly. Like in a SQL `GROUP BY`, all fields returned should be either part of `GROUP BY` or aggregate functions.

There are few options to actually get more data alongside the aggregations:

- the search results themselves (the `hits` part);
- [`top_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) aggregation, which allows to have a few most relevant documents for a given bucket.

#### How many sub aggregations we can add?

I cannot find any relevant documentation or a configuration setting that would allow to have a sure answer. However, there is `index.max_docvalue_fields_search` setting that defaults to `100` in [Dynamic index settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/index-modules.html#dynamic-index-settings). Since aggregations use [`doc_values`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/doc-values.html), I'd say that around 100 bucket aggregations is a reasonable upper limit.

I believe that the limitation here is the actual performance of your Elasticsearch cluster.

#### Can we have all resulted fields in same bucket?

It can be done, but might be not efficient. You may use [`script`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-script) mode of `terms` aggregation. The query might look like this:

```
POST bidder_server_stats/doc/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "via script": {
      "terms": {
        "script": {
          "source": "doc['bc'].value +':::'+ doc['log_dt_st'].value ",
          "lang": "painless"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sum(avg_price)": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "avg_price"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the result will look like the following:

```
{
  ...
  "aggregations": {
    "via script": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "2513:::2018-06-08T06:36:16.073Z",
          "doc_count": 2,
          "sum(avg_price)": {
            "value": 16.800000190734863
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "2514:::2018-06-08T06:36:16.073Z",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "sum(avg_price)": {
            "value": 10
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In order to perform this aggregation Elasticsearch will have to compute the bucket value for each document matching the query, which is an equivalent of the full scan in SQL. Aggregations instead are more like index look-ups, since they use `doc_values` data representation, a data structure that makes these look-ups efficient.

In some cases `script` buckets can be a solution, but their scope is quite limited. In case you are interested in `script`-based solution there is also [scripted metric aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html) to consider.

Hope that helps!

#### Update: Since ES 6.1 it is possible to do with `composite` aggregation

In Elasticsearch 6.1 [`composite`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.1/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html) aggregation was added. As of 6.3, it is still marked as [experimental](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html) (so the API might change, or this feature could be removed completely in the future).

The query in this case would look like:

```
POST bidder_server_stats/doc/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "my composite": {
      "composite": {
        "sources": [
          {
            "bc": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "bc"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "log_dt_st": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "log_dt_st"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sum(avg_price)": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "avg_price"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the response:

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "my composite": {
      "after_key": {
        "bc": "2514",
        "log_dt_st": 1528439776073
      },
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": {
            "bc": "2513",
            "log_dt_st": 1528439776073
          },
          "doc_count": 2,
          "sum(avg_price)": {
            "value": 16.800000190734863
          }
        },
        {
          "key": {
            "bc": "2514",
            "log_dt_st": 1528439776073
          },
          "doc_count": 1,
          "sum(avg_price)": {
            "value": 10
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Some doubts <br/>  1. Can we have some more fields in result set without adding them into aggregations.  <br/> 2. How many sub aggregations we can add.<br/> 3. Can we have all resulted fields in same bucket. <br/><br/>Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much @Nikolay.

Comment: @DeepakHasani Thank you. Feel free to do a +1 to the answer if you find it useful :)

Comment: @DeepakHasani I updated the answer with a new ES feature that does just what you were asking, in case you are interested.

Comment: Thank you @Nikolay. I have one more question. Can you please tell me how to do limit in above query ' "from" :1,"size":10" ' is not working in this.

Comment: @DeepakHasani you mean in `composite` aggregation?

Comment: No. in your previous reply without composite aggregations

Comment: You could use [`size`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-size)    param of the terms aggregation, although you can't use `from` because it doesn't allow pagination.

Comment: Thank you @Nikolay. Sorry but i have one more question. How can we use round function in elasticsearch

Comment: This goes beyond the scope of this topic, I believe it is irrelevant.

Comment: OK..Thanks anyways @Nikolay