# How to apply exact match on single field and distinct on multiple fields together in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I recently started working on ElasticSearch, and I am trying search for following criteria

[image: I have following data i.e. as shown in image in my index.]

I want to apply exact match on ENAME & distinct on both EID & ENAME on above data.
Let say for matching, I have string ABC.
So result should be like as below

```
[
  {"EID" :111, "ENAME" : "ABC"},
  {"EID" : 444, "ENAME" : "ABC"}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this via a combination of [`term`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/query-dsl-term-query.html) query and [`terms`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) [aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/search-aggregations.html).

Assuming that you have the following [mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/mapping.html):

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "EID": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "ENAME": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And inserted the documents like this:

```
POST my_index/doc/3
{
  "EID": "111",
  "ENAME": "ABC"
}

POST my_index/doc/4
{
  "EID": "222",
  "ENAME": "XYZ"
}

POST my_index/doc/12
{
  "EID": "444",
  "ENAME": "ABC"
}
```

The query that will do the job might look like this:

```
POST my_index/doc/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": { 1️⃣
      "ENAME": "ABC"
    }
  },
  "size": 0, 3️⃣
  "aggregations": {
    "by EID": {
      "terms": { 2️⃣
        "field": "EID"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Let me explain how it works:

- 1️⃣ - `term` query asks Elasticsearch to filter on exact value of a [`keyword`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/keyword.html) field `"ENAME"`;
- 2️⃣ - `terms` aggregation collects the list of all possible values of another `keyword` field `"EID"` and gives back the first N most frequent ones;
- 3️⃣ - `"size": 0` tells Elasticsearch not to return any search hits (we are only interested in the aggregations).

The output of the query will look like this:

```
{
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "by EID": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "111",  <== Here is the first "distinct" value that we wanted 
          "doc_count": 3
        },
        {
          "key": "444", <== Here is another "distinct" value
          "doc_count": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The output does not look exactly like what you posted in the question, but I believe it is the closest what you can achieve with Elasticsearch.

However, this output is equivalent:

- `"ENAME"` is implicitly present (since its value was used for filtering)
- `"EID"` is present under the `"buckets"` of the aggregations section.

Note that under `"doc_count"` you will find the number of documents having such `"EID"`.

#### What if I want to do a `DISTINCT` on several fields?

For a more complex scenario (e.g. when you need to do a distinct on many fields) see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51273857/5095957).

More information about aggregations is available [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/search-aggregations.html).

Hope that helps!