# Sorting on multiple buckets at ones in Elastic

Tags: elasticsearch

I am currently working on grouping result in aggs and apparently there are some documents will not be included but I can have them in a second bucket.

However, now I am losing the ability sort on them all. I thought Composite Aggregation can be the key in here.

But, it is not allowing to use filters and top hits.

Below you may find the agg I use.

Because there are 4 buckets I cannot do  *sorting*  and  *pagination*.

```
"aggs": { "prefix": { "filter": { "prefix": { "name": { "value": "in" } } }, "aggs": { "platforms": { "terms": { "field": "name", "size": 100, "include": "in.", "order": { "_key": "asc" } }, "aggs": { "platform": { "top_hits": { "_source": true, "size": 1 } } } } } }, "second": { "filter": { "wildcard": { "name": " in*" } }, "aggs": { "platforms": { "terms": { "field": "name", "size": 100, "order": { "_key": "asc" } }, "aggs": { "platform": { "top_hits": { "_source": true, "size": 1 } } } } } }, "middle": { "filter": { "wildcard": { "name": "in" } }, "aggs": { "platforms": { "terms": { "field": "name", "size": 100, "order": { "_key": "asc" } }, "aggs": { "platform": { "top_hits": { "_source": true, "size": 1 } } } } } }, "suffix": { "filter": { "wildcard": { "name": "*in" } }, "aggs": { "platforms": { "terms": { "field": "name", "size": 100, "order": { "_key": "asc" } }, "aggs": { "platform": { "top_hits": { "_source": true, "size": 1 } } } } } } }
```

Any idea?

Cheers,
emsi

Comment: Did you try `script` mode of `terms` aggregation? It could do the trick. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51273857/5095957) for example.

Comment: May I ask you iwhen you say you are "losing the ability to sort on them all" you refer to [bucket sort aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-sort-aggregation.html) or I am getting it wrong?

Comment: Thanks for links! 
Because the field I am grouping by is "null" on some documents thus I am not getting all of them grouped in bucket. Can this be done with a script?

Comment: Should be possible, it would help if you could post a couple of example queries, the mapping you use and the desired output.

Comment: Sure, I have updated the post.

Comment: Thanks for the query. Still I am not able to understand what you are trying to do. A few example documents and the desired output would help. In the meantime, take a look at [`filters aggregation`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filters-aggregation.html) since it can simplify your query and on [`bucket script`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-script-aggregation.html) aggregation since it is more flexible.

Comment: Actually, I still need to handle pagination in PHP but I can simplify the aggs in the query now if I use filters also it looks more readable. Thanks!